# EASYSMPP- Capture the exact reponses from SMPP server

Tags: smpp, server-response

I am using EASYSMPP to send SMSes through an  SMPP server, however am unable to capture the exact responses from the SMSC because the function client.SendSMS, returns either TRUE(for sent SMS) or FALSE(for a failed SMS). I want to be able to log those responses so that I can share with the service provider for analysis.
Kindly assist.